# How to convert Euclidean distances between vectors to similarity scores

Tags: python, vector, numpy, distance, similarity

Below is my code for calculating Euclidean distance between vectors, and a snippet of my transformed data set (vectors).

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

vect=[[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1],
 [1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

for u1, u2 in itertools.combinations(vect, 2):
    x = np.array(u1)
    y = np.array(u2)
    space = np.linalg.norm(y - x)
    print space
```

The Euclidean distances between the vectors are:

```
7.0
5.56776436283
4.472135955
```

My goal is to compute the similarity between the vectors and output a similarity score for each comparison. Typical similarity score lies between 0 and 1, with 0-being not similar and 1-exactly similar. The question here is how can I convert the Euclidean distances to similarity scores? 
Someone suggested this formula: 1/1+d(P1, P2) ie inverse of Euclidean distance=similarity score.Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Does the suggestion not work?

Comment: It makes sense to me, but I haven't tried it yet. I was just hoping there could be better ideas out there.

Comment: It really depends on how you want to define similarity. Should `(-1, -1)` be more similar to `(5, 2)` than `(1000, 0)` is to `(1007, 0)`? If so, distance isn't enough information. Also, it depends on what you're going to use this information for, and what your scale requirements are.

Comment: s/if so/if not/ (too late to edit the comment)

Comment: @user2357112, my scale requirement is 0-1, and this information will be used to measure document's similarity. (1000,0) and (1007,0) is supposed to be more similar than (-1,-1) and (5,2). Higher values for euclidean distances are supposed to reflect less similarity than lower values.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of similarity-measures out there. As user2357112 says, the *best* one depends on your application. I suggest taking a look at some of the kernels listed here:

http://crsouza.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/kernel-functions-for-machine-learning.html

I have found the chi-square kernel to be a good default choice in my applications - particularly if the vectors are histograms.

If you have a subset of data for which you know already which ones you would like to be similar to each other i would suggest trying some different kernels and plotting the resultant similarity matrix over these samples ( if you had 100 test samples you would get a 100x100 similarity matrix that you could plot simply as an heat map using the imshow method in matplotlib.pyplot).